# Integracion de datos de una misma tabla

Tags: sql-server

Alguien puede ayudarme a integrar datos de una misma tabla tipo nomenclatura en sql server? ejemplo:

la columna nivel tiene distintos niveles, que las nivel 2 integren a nivel 1, las nivel 3 integren nivel 2 y asi sucesivamente

[image: 1]

y todo en la misma vista

[image: 2]

Comment: Que es lo que buscas exactamente?
ordenar por código de bodega?

Comment: Lo que busco es que la sub bodega (ejemplo: 1A010101) integre a su bodega madre, y que lo vaya separando por grupos como muestra la segunda imagen

Comment: Los códigos de bodega siempre tendrán la misma estructura o se tiene que buscar el código común?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. 1. Creo que hace falta definir qué es "integrar". 2. Los datos de ejemplo publícalos como texto, no como imagenes. 3. Debe haber alguna manera de relacionar hijos con padres. Lo habitual y más flexible es almacenar en el hijo el código o el ID del padre. Si no se hace así probablemente fijando las longitudes de cada nivel sea lo único óptimo. Si no, no hay de otra que ir buscando cada posible sub-cadena como padre, lo cual daría lugar a una consulta bastante menos eficiente.

Comment: ok, entonces lo que buscas es que en el 4to registro diga: Grupo1 = 1, Grupo2 = 1A,  Grupo 3 = 1A0101?

Comment: exactamente, ese es el resultado que necesito

Comment: puedes agregar el código de tu vista?

Answer (score 0):

El resultado que buscas se puede obtener por medio de una CTE recursiva. Sin embargo, esta herramienta es complicada y puede causar problemas de rendimiento en el sistema si no se usa con cuidado.

Para iniciar, las CTEs son consultas que se definen antes de una consulta principal en la que se puede usar como una tabla. En sí, se pueden definir como vistas en línea o subconsultas refactorizadas. Ahora, las CTEs recursivas pueden llamarse a si mismas y se conforman de una consulta ancla que se une a la consulta recursiva.

En tu caso, la consulta ancla es simplemente obtener las filas con el nivel 1, definiendo todas las columnas que requerirás. En la parte recursiva, vas agregando los datos según se requiera y con cada nivel decides si obtienes los datos del grupo de de la misma columna o del código de la bodega.

Dejo el ejemplo de como hacerlo, así como el ejemplo de como deberás incluir los datos de prueba en el futuro.

```
CREATE TABLE Bodegas(
    EMP_NIT     varchar(20),
    CODBODEGA   varchar(20),
    DESBODEGA   varchar(100),
    NIVEL       tinyint
)
INSERT INTO Bodegas 
VALUES
( '9556010-6', '1'         , 'TODAS'                                          , 1),
( '9556010-6', '1A'        , 'PROABENSA'                                      , 2),
( '9556010-6', '1A0101'    , 'BODEGA MIXTA'                                   , 3),
( '9556010-6', '1A010101'  , 'BODEGA MIXTA'                                   , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010102'  , 'BODEGA COMPRAS DIRECTAS'                        , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A0102'    , 'BODEGA DE MATERIAS PRIMAS CONCENTRADO'          , 3),
( '9556010-6', '1A010201'  , 'BODEGA DE MATERIAS PRIMAS CONCENTRADO'          , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A0103'    , 'BODEGA DE PRODUCTO TERMINADO'                   , 3),
( '9556010-6', '1A010301'  , 'BODEGA MIS CARNES'                              , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010302'  , 'FABRICA DE CONCENTRADOS'                        , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A0104'    , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS'            , 3),
( '9556010-6', '1A010401'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS GESTACION'  , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010402'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS MATERNIDAD' , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010403'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS DESTETE'    , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010404'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS ENGORDE'    , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010405'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS MUERTOS'    , 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A010406'  , 'BODEGA DE RECEPCION DE CONCENTRADOS NACIMIENTOS', 4),
( '9556010-6', '1A01040601', 'BODEGA #1'                                      , 5),
( '9556010-6', '1A01040602', 'BODEGA #2'                                      , 5);


WITH rcteBodegas AS(
    SELECT EMP_NIT,
            CODBODEGA,
            DESBODEGA,
            NIVEL,
            CAST( NULL AS varchar(20)) AS GRUPO1,
            CAST( NULL AS varchar(20)) AS GRUPO2,
            CAST( NULL AS varchar(20)) AS GRUPO3,
            CAST( NULL AS varchar(20)) AS GRUPO4
    FROM Bodegas
    WHERE Nivel = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  b.EMP_NIT,
            b.CODBODEGA,
            b.DESBODEGA,
            b.NIVEL,
            CASE WHEN b.NIVEL = 2 THEN r.CODBODEGA ELSE r.GRUPO1 END AS GRUPO1,
            CASE WHEN b.NIVEL = 3 THEN r.CODBODEGA ELSE r.GRUPO2 END AS GRUPO2,
            CASE WHEN b.NIVEL = 4 THEN r.CODBODEGA ELSE r.GRUPO3 END AS GRUPO3,
            CASE WHEN b.NIVEL = 5 THEN r.CODBODEGA ELSE r.GRUPO4 END AS GRUPO4
    FROM Bodegas b
    JOIN rcteBodegas r ON b.Nivel = r.NIVEL + 1 
                      AND b.CODBODEGA LIKE r.CODBODEGA + '%' 
)
SELECT *
FROM rcteBodegas
ORDER BY CODBODEGA;
```